# Z-index not working for Embed Code

Tags: html, css, wordpress

While scrolling my web page a DIV which have a video is not going behind the top DIV.
On my web page a top DIV,which have folloing css styling

```
#header{
font-size:11px;
height:25px;
position:fixed;
top:0;
width:960px;
z-index:1000;
}
```

Now after clearing all floated element,I added a video on a wrapper DIV like same as this way..

```
<div id="vedio">
<object>video code</object>
</div>
```

Applying CSS

```
#vedio{
position:relative;
text-align:center;
z-index:0;
}
```

After doing all stuff video is not going behind header in FireFox3.6,Google Chrome.Please Someone Help me out.
Thank you

Comment: Which browser are you using? Internet Explorer tends to have many z-index issues with form elements, embeds, etc.

Comment: Its not working on firefox3.6,chrome

Comment: Do you have a live example we could see?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Which Browser are you testing in? IE has `z-index:0;` issues, always start with `1` or `-1` and go from there.

**Edit:**

Add this to your object:

`<param name="wmode" value="transparent">`

and this to your embed:

`wmode="transparent"` and remember to close your embed tag with either `</embed>` or seeing as you're using XHTML doctype: `/>`. I added these in firebug and it works fine :)

```
<object width="606" height="385">
            <param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/RjUIarUAioY&hl=en_US&fs=1&color1=0x2b405b&color2=0x6b8ab6"></param>
            <param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param>
            <param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param>
            <param name="wmode" value="transaprent"></param>
            <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/RjUIarUAioY&hl=en_US&fs=1&color1=0x2b405b&color2=0x6b8ab6"
                   type="application/x-shockwave-flash"
                   allowscriptaccess="always"
                   allowfullscreen="true"
                   width="606" height="385"
                   wmode="transparent">
            </embed>
        </object>
```

You also had `z-index; 999;` on `#wp-admin-bar *`, I added it to the parent; `#wp-admin-bar .padder` just to make sure the children would inherit the value.

Comment: Its not working on Firefox3.6,Chrome.I am not talking about IE.

Comment: Hey Kyle thanks for your useful information but whatever the code given by you, I tried the same but it didn't work. you can check it from firebug.

Comment: Again The same problem..I did all the stuff but still very away from my goal..Please have a look ons again..thank you

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo in the answer, `transaprent` should be `transparent`. My bad. Edited to fix. And you still haven't closed the `embed` tag.

Answer (score 1):

In the `object` of video, try setting a `param`:

```
wmode = transparent
```

Answer (score 1):

Typo in

value="transaprent" change to value="transparent"